# How can i do better query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to search a user that is not in specific group.
I have a working query in MYSQL and i need some advice and some help.
Here is my query.

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM users WHERE
id NOT IN (
                SELECT user_id FROM group_members WHERE group_id = $groupId
            )            
AND fullname LIKE $serchKey
```

the subquery is getting all id on a group then use it as reference in WHERE clause (id NOT IN) of main query, I have no large data by now. i think if i have large data and getting all id as reference use in (id NOT IN) i think it will took large time before getting the result. what can you say?
can you give me a good suggestions for this. thanks

Comment: we would need to see your show create table and know mysql engine version for this - `NOT IN` typically gives great performance in 5.6 but it all depends on the data, engine ver. and the query.

Comment: @cerd i use SELECT version(); on phpmyadmin in our server on our webhosting and this is the result

5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

sorry i am lessthan a year in programming. i will go now. maybe i will look for all the response later.. and actually, i dont have any problem using that query by now. im just worrying that maybe later it will be problem when the data became large, but when you say NOT IN i gives great performance my worry is gone now thanks

Comment: I misspoke. I meant `NOT EXISTS` -- this should give better performance than `NOT IN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is the best way as I can think of with relate to the condition and code maintainability.

```
SELECT id, fullname 
FROM users 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM group_members WHERE group_id = $groupId)
  AND fullname LIKE $serchKey
```

But there is an alternative using `LEFT JOIN` which is arguable on the performance. *(I didnt check this SQL, please check it in your DB)*

```
SELECT distinct u.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN group_members gm
  ON u.id = gm.user_id
WHERE gm.user_id IS NULL 
  AND u.fullname like $serchkey
```

Comment: i will try later i need to go by now, thaks for reply

Comment: thanks for stating that the performance is arguable - can never know without an actual benchmark.